# Parse - How to prevent intent to fire up automatically when receiving push notification [Android]

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, parse-platform

I've successfully implemented advance targeting with JSONObject and able to send and receive notifications. I also set my default callback `PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, myActivity.class);.`

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` and `onReceive()` which will access all the data passed via the payload. I also have an Intent inside the onReceive function which will fire up an activity with some additional data passed to that activity via `putExtra();`.

My problem now is that when i receive the notification, it automatically start the intent activity which i've stated in the `onReceive()` function. What i want to do is to start the onReceive's intent activity only if the user Tap/Click on the push notification message on the system tray.

I tried so many ways to solve this yet i keep on failing. Any suggestions? I can provide additional code if needed. Thank you.

EDIT: The intent's activity should start when the user tap on the push notification no matter if the app is on the foreground or background. Thanks.

Well, i decided to paste my onReceive() here :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));

        Iterator itr = json.keys();
        ArrayList arraylist = new ArrayList();

        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) itr.next();

            arraylist.add(json.getString(key));
        }

        Intent intentComment = new Intent(context, comments.class);
        intentComment.putExtra("post_id", arraylist.get(3).toString());
        intentComment.putExtra("btnFlag", arraylist.get(2).toString());
        intentComment.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intentComment);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: You can look at my solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557968/parse-push-notification-alert-dialog-not-appearing-when-app-is-closed/25984167#25984167